CUPS-PDF Cannot Print JPG or PNG Logo in WINE
Ubuntu Version: 24.04.1
WINE Version: 9.18
The CUPS-PDF printer that I have on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 cannot print a PNG or a JPG logo that is embedded on the printout page of a Windows-only database programme running inside WINE 9.18. I have already tried scaling-down the image/logo as well as scaling down the DPI to 150 but to no avail. All the other graphics like lines and boxes print out well and it's just the logo, which we need for the business, that is not printing, at all.
Has anyone got any solutions to this? Cheers.
EDIT: The programme is Filemaker Pro which runs OK on WINE, as in everything functions as usual, but when I am printing an invoice, for example, everything in the printout is there except for the the JPG or PNG logo. I noticed that CUPS-PDF cannot print any JPG or PNG that is embedded on the printout.


The first image is an example invoice, pulled from the web, which has JPG or PNG embedded in it. The second example is what CUPS-PDF would print.

For something ultra specific like this...you;re probably gonna need to give specifics.

Thanks. I added the following to the original message: The programme is Filemaker Pro which runs OK on WINE, as in everything functions as usual, but when I am printing an invoice, for example, everything in the printout is there except for the the JPG or PNG logo. I noticed that CUPS-PDF cannot print any JPG or PNG that is embedded on the printout.

so you're printing from within WINE and it's not printing the JPG/PNG?  It's still unclear where you're hitting "print" from - the Filemaker Pro WINE program, or after you've exported in the native PDF reader or such of Ubuntu

Yes, I am printing through a Print button with scripts I made to bring out the print dialogue box, which contains the CUPS-PDF selection. Basically, I am printing out a scaled-layout from within the database. There isn't an option to export a PDF copy before bringing out the print dialogue box.
